# Not uploading image on Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm new in CakePHP, I'm creating a application using this framework now I'm suffering a little bit problem, not uploading image but image name save to database. below my code:

```
public function save()
{
    $shop = TableRegistry::get('shop');
    $query = $shop->query();
    //

    $product = $this->request->data('prductname');
    $domain = $this->request->data('domainname');
    $phone = $this->request->data('phone');

    if (!empty($this->request->data)) 
    {
       $file = $this->request->data['file'];
    }

        $filename = $file;
        $file_tmp_name = $filename;
        $dir = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'uploads';
        $allowed = array('png','jpg','jpeg' );
        if (!in_array(substr(strrchr($filename,'.'),1),$allowed)) 
        {
            throw new InternalErrorException("Error Processing Request", 1);
        }
        elseif(is_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name))
        {
            $filename = Text::uuid().'-'.$filename;
            $fileDB = TableRegistry::get('shop');
            $entity = $fileDB->newEntity();
            $entity->filename = $filename;
            $fileDB->save($entity);
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $dir.DS.$filename);
        }

    $query->insert([

        'prductname','domainname','phone','file'

    ])->values([

        'prductname'=>$product,
        'domainname'=>$domain,
        'phone'=>$phone,
        'file' => $file

    ])->execute();

    if ($query) 
    {
        $this->Flash->success('This information has been saved.');
        $this->redirect(['controller'=>'shop','action'=>'index']);
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create(null,['url'=>['controller'=>'Shop', 'action'=>'save']],['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']); 
?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="product">Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prductname" placeholder="Name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="domain">Domain Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="domainname" class="form-control" placeholder="Domain Name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="InputFile">File input</label>
        <input type="file" name="file">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Not Showing any error, image name saving to DB but not replacing image to target folder.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide us the code for the function `move_uploaded_file();` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `$file_tmp_name` might be incorrect for what `move_uploaded_file` expects.  `move_uploaded_file` expects the `$tmp_name` to be the unique string that PHP assigns to each uploaded file.  I'm not sure exactly what structure `$this->request->data['file']` will have, but the `$_FILES` array has array keys such as `'name'`, `'size'`, `'tmp_name'`, and `'type'`.  You need to use the `'tmp_name'` found here in `move_uploaded_file`.  This might be present in `$this->request->data`, and if so it would be better practice to use the `'tmp_name'` from that array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php